# Changing class to generic type

Tags: java, generics

I'm trying to solve a problem where in a Queue and Products, instead of having the products as integers in the queue, I need them to be stored more generally by using generic classes. But apart from adding the generic bits to the class names I'm not sure what to do.

The product class:

```
public class Product{
    private int barcode;

    public Product(int barcode){
        this.barcode = barcode;
    }
}
```

And a class for a bounded queue:

```
public class BQ{
    private final int[] elements;
    private int number, begin, end;

public BQ(int size) {
    elements = new int[size];
    number = 0;
    begin = 0;
    end = 0;
}

public void add(int item) {
    ...
}

public int remove(){
    ...
}

public boolean isEmpty(){
    return number == 0;
}
```

}

To start I changed the Product class to:    `public class Product<T>`
As far as I know there's nothing left to be changed in this class. Aside from the barcode attribute there isn't anything else there.

Now I'm running into problems in the BQ class.

The first step that came to mind was to change the class to: `public class BQ<Product>`

This code still executes but I find it hard to believe this is actually all there is to it. What I also would like to know is what does this change apart from just using types, what is the advantage of this?

Comment: I don't get what you are trying to do. Are you setting the `barcode` as a `T` ? If not, like you said, you don't need it. Then, in `BQ`, where are you using `Product` ? And `public class BQ<Product>` is not what you want, this will create a generic BQ class, nothing to do with `Product`. I guess you just want to create your `BQ` generic like `BQ<T>`, to set elements ilke `T[]`

Comment: Right now products are put in the queue as integers, but they should be stored as Products. So `barcode` wouldn't become a `T` but the entire class would. But I could totally be wrong on this

Comment: If what you want is to create an instance `Product` to store those `integers` previously in the queue. You don't need generic ... If you want then to store those instance in the queue, you don't need generic... What type `barcode` could have ? It look to me that you have baldy design your project, you might want to have multiple class for `BarCode` depending on the types (code 128, code 39, ...).

Comment: Well the thing is this is part of an assignment, which states to change `BQ` to `BQ<Product>` but I kinda feel like that doesnt make sense. if anything that should be `BQ<T>` right?

Comment: Unless it is stating that the instance should be declared as `BQ<Product>` then, indeed the class should be `public class BQ<T>`

Comment: Turns out I could indeed use `BQ<T>` instead of `BQ<Product>`. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

No point in parameterizing `Product` - it's `BQ` you want to use for generic items.

So you first define the queue as `BQ<T>` and think of `T` as "whatever type of items I ant to hold".

Now, since you no longer want to hold `int`s but now want to store "whatever type needed" (i.e. `T`), you first change `int[] elements` to `T[] elements` - that's the semantic change you wanted to accomplish - storing "whatever type" instead of `int`s.

Then, you'll have to adjust all the methods that work with this array (`add` etc.) to now expect items of type `T` instead of `int`s - that should be fairly straightforward.

And that should be all you need to do in `BQ` class. Now, to use this class to store products, you instantiate it like this:

```
BQ<Product> productQueue = new BQ<Product>(size);
```